# Crawling a webpage using R

Tags: r

For the website - http://www.audiworld.com/forums/q5-sq5-discussion-129/sunroof-window-exploded-18c-see-pictures-2819091/

I am trying to crawl a webpage using R, I can crawl the text from the webpages and store each in a single text file.

Now I want to store each comment in a text file, and access pages 2 and 3 of the website. I will appreciate any help,

Here is the code I have

```
addresses <- read.table("YY.csv") # Create a .csv file with all of the links you want to crawl


    for (i in addresses) full.text <- getURL(i) 


text.sub <- gsub("<.+?>", "", full.text) # Removes HTML tags
text <- data.frame(text.sub)


outpath <- "outputpath" #output path
x <- 1:nrow(text)
for(i in x) {
  write(as.character(text[i,1]), file = paste(outpath,"/",i,".txt",sep="")) #write the text, each website per text file
}
```

Comment: Depending on what you're doing with said text files, this may violate section 4 of their [terms and conditions](http://www.internetbrands.com/ibterms/?site=AudiWorld.com), since it's unlikely you qualify as a _general purpose Internet search engine_ or are building/maintaining a _noncommercial public archive_. These TOUs may seen silly, but they carry serious legal weight. If you have permission, please link to it somewhere, otherwise any help by anyone is also in violation.

Comment: I do not have any permission. For an arbitrary website like google.com, can I get a help on how to copy data from other pages (pages 2, 3 and so on)